# safely remove Ubuntu EFI partition and move windows EFI partition to free space

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bios, uefi, grub

Problem #1: I messed up my Windows once and it wouldn't start so I had to reinstall using a flash drive, during installation I deleted the EFI partition and the free space is still there but windows made another EFI partition and now I have free space and then EFI partition for windows. How do I move it to that free space?[Image below RED]

Problem #2: I installed ubuntu again and I messed up with diskpart while moving my partitions and it accidentally deleted boot/efi/grub although I still get grub and it shows a bunch of options but nothing works and I had to manually change the boot order to windows so I can boot into windows and use my laptop. Now, the problem is how do I remove grub safely, also it still shows in disk management as healthy EFI partition - Image below GREEN.
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved this thing on my own. Here's how it goes - First of all the EFI partition I'm talking about in Problem #1 turns out that it's not EFI partition but it's Win Recovery Tools and I deleted them during my fresh windows install and the memory left before them, I merged it with my C drive using AOEMI partition tool and then for Problem #2- it's actually fairly simple -

1. Start Powershell with admin privileges.
2. write "diskpart"
3. write "list disk" and "sel disk #(disk number)"
4. write "list vol" and choose the volume with FAT32, it should be generally around ~100MB
5. write "ASSIGN LETTER=S:"
6. write "exit"
7. "cd /S"
8. "ls" and select "cd EFI"
9. "ls" and delete ubuntu by command "rm -r ubuntu"
   And, that's it that will solve both my problems!

Answer (score -1):

You can use disk partition software like partition magic that can help you remove the Linux partitions and make it unpartitioned space. Post making unpartioned format it as NTFS and it will be merged with windows.

You can use the free version of partition magic for this.